# Deleted app data, application in emulator not starting

Tags: android, android-studio

I am building my first Android App and I implemented a connection to a SQLite database. From what I understood that database was stored locally. During testing I had added trash values to this database from my app for testing. After I got past that bug, accessing those trash values would cause the app to crash. Since there was no way for me to delete the values from the database in the app, I deleted the app data from the settings. 
When I tried running my app over again, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myname.appname/com.example.myname.appname.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myname.appname.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myname.appname-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myname.appname-2/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
```

I can't run my app in Android Studio at all. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you'r not showing any piece of code and that's No Good for me to debug .but anyways please  try the following steps :

- Go To Build in android studio
- Click clean project
- and then go back to Build again and click Rebuild project

This would reset things correctly

otherwise you would be having a  package mismatch error

another cause of the problem is that

```
android-support-v(x)
```

in the gradel should be changed  :**where x is version number**

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago, I got the problem same on you. 
You should find out and remove database file on your emulator (using Manager App), such as default path like this (I don't remember exactly): /data/data/your.app.package/databases/your_db.db3

Some tips for you:

- Should add the database version, if you have a change, increase value and put the if statement
- SQLite DB is not a DBMS, I recommend you use Realm